# d3 graph rendering with vue

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Because of non compatible dependencies, I have to downgrade from vue3 to vue2.
I have created a force directed graph with D3 library. Everything worked find with vue3 using composition api. I am not familiar with vue 2 and adapting my graph to vue2 has not been working out for me.
In vue3 it was very straitforward and ref() made it pretty easy to accomplish.
As for vue2, I have tried making good use of lifecycle hooks such as computed and watch

Any help is more than welcome

Here is a minimalistic representation of my working component in vue3. This component creates the graph in a svg and then renders it in the template.

```
<template>
 <div class="col" style="position: absolute; width:100%; height:100%" >
     <div class="main-map-container" style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%;">
         <div ref="graph" class="canvas">
                
         </div>
     </div> 
 </div>
</template>

<script >
import {onMounted, onBeforeMount, ref} from 'vue'
export default {
setup(){

   const graph = ref() 
   const links = [{src:"Amazon",target:"Aurora"},{src:"Amazon",target:"Aurora"},{src:"Amazon",target:"Zoox"},{src:"Amazon",target:"Rivian"}]
   const nodes = [{id:"Amazon"},{id:"Aurora"},{id:"Zoox"},{id:"Rivian"}]


    onBeforeMount( async ()=>{
        const svgobj = ForceGraph(nodes, links)
        graph.value.appendChild(svgobj);
        })



    function ForceGraph(
    nodes, 
    links
    ){
   // The code for the graph has been removed since it is much too long
    return Object.assign( svg.node() );
    }


    return { graph }
    }
}
</script>
<style></style>
```

This is the vue2 component that i have emptied for this post

```
<template>
 <div class="col" style="position: absolute; width:100%; height:100%" >
     <div class="main-map-container" style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%;">
         <div ref="graph" class="canvas">
                
         </div>
     </div> 
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  setup(){
   
  },

methods: {

    },

watch: {

    },

props: {
      
    },

computed: {

    },

created() {

    },

mounted() {

    },

 updated(){
    
 },

 data() {
      return {
}}



}
</script>


<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Vue3` composition API in vue 2. Install the composition api and then just keep your code the same, with the `setup` method exactly as it was.

The `setup` method, lifecycle hooks, and all the reactivity (refs and reactive objects) are made available to you, with very few incompatibilities.

We use `d3` with `Vue2` in this fashion all the time. 100% compatible.

https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api